# Google+ Snippet content customization on Facebook tabs

Tags: facebook, google-plus, google-plus-one

I'm curious if anyone has had success controlling content shared by Google+'s +1 and Share buttons on Facebook tabs. I'm seeing Google scrape content from the brand's main page (http://www.facebook.com/brand) instead of the tab itself (http://www.facebook.com/brand/app_123456789).

I've tried the microdata and Open Graph tag methods documented for the G+ Snippet but I see no difference. https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet/ And I don't see a way to build my own share URL like you can with Facebook's dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own share URL using the Share Endpoint: https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#sharelink-endpoint

Comment: The share endpoint only takes a URL and language code for parameters, so the shared content is still based on what Google's scraper picks up. Compare this to the FB feed dialog, where you can specify heading, description, image, etc.

Comment: You can control the snippet (title, image and description) using schema.org markup: https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/